# Probability that the second ball is atleast more than three larger than the first one

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have a box with balls labeled $1, \dots, n, n \geq 4$. Suppose I choose $B_1$ from the box, and then $B_2$ from it without replacement. I want to compute $P[B_2 > B_1 + 3]$.

To do this, I was considering an argument via the law of total probability. Breaking this down into conditioning on $B_1$ we find that:

$$
P[B_2 > B_1 + 3] = \frac{1}{n} \left( P[B_2 > B_1 + 3 \mid B_1 = 1] + \dots + P[B_2 > B_1 + 3 \mid B_1 = n-4] \right)
$$

We can write $P[B_2 > k + 3 | B_2 = k]$ as $\frac{n-(k+3)}{n-1}$. So we can write out our answer as:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-4} \frac{1}{n} \frac{n-(k+3)}{n-1}
$$

I'm preparing for my midterm, and I came across this problem that I was able to solve rather dirtily with the Law of Total Probability. I was wondering if there was a nicer argument via random variables. I understand that $B_1$ is a uniform discrete r.v., but how do I define $B_2$, given that the sample space is dependent on what $B_1$ is?

Comment: The words say "$3$ greater", the formula says "more than $3$ greater". Which one do you want?

Comment: Ah that's a typo in the title, I want the set of balls greater than the first one by atleast 3, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All $N=n(n-1)/2$ possible ordered pairs have the same probability, so we can just count the number of outcomes. I hope this picture will give you a hint how to do it.

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, of course it's just a counting argument on the upper $n+4$ diagonals of a $n \times n$ matrix. I'll accept this answer, it's very tidy.